# Position fixed taking much space

Tags: html, css, position

I'm really confused with positioning div. As I try to make header fixed on the top, but another div after header, it's screwed and taking much space..

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="header-center">
        <div id="headerleft">
            <h1> <a href="link"> LOGO </a> </h1>
        </div>

        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li> <a href="link" LINK </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="link" LINK </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="link" LINK </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="link" LINK </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="link" LINK </a> </li>
             </ul>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="article">
    <p> HELLO </p>
</div>
```

And here is my CSS

```
#header {
height:60px;
backgroundcolor:rgba(51,102,153,1);
color:#FFF;
position:fixed;
bottom:0;left:0;right:0;top:0;
z-index:9999;
}

#article {
margin:0 auto;
}
```

And here is my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8kkS6/1/).

So, I don't know where I need to put position fixed, absolute, relative on which div above. I'm so confused as I want to make header on the top when we scroll down.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: This: `bottom:0;left:0;right:0;top:0;` is contradictory. You can either have `bottom` or `top` and `left` or `right`.

Comment: Your usage of fixed position is correct for the header. You just need to set an appropriate top margin or padding for `#article` to account for the space taken by the header. If you're not sure when to use `static`, `relative`, `fixed`, or `absolute` for the element position, then it might be worthwhile to read up on them to have a better understanding of when to use each. [Here's a very useful article](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#header {
    height:60px;
    backgroundcolor:rgba(51,102,153,1);
    color:#FFF;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    right： 0;
    top:0;
    z-index:9999;
}
#header-center {
    margin: 0 auto; width: 960px;
}
#headerleft {
    float: left;
}
#nav {
    float: left;//this depends on what your design looks like!
}
#article {
    margin:60px auto 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close.  First off, close all your anchor tags:

```
                <li> <a href="link"> LINK </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="link"> LINK </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="link"> LINK </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="link"> LINK </a> </li>
                <li> <a href="link"> LINK </a> </li>
```

Next up you need to make sure the page is long enough to need to scroll.

Have a look at this:
http://jsfiddle.net/8kkS6/4/

```
 <div id="article">
    <p> HELLO </p>
    <p> HELLO </p>
    <p> HELLO </p>
    <p> HELLO </p>
    <p> HELLO </p>
    <p> HELLO </p>
    <p> HELLO </p>
    <p> HELLO </p>
    <p> HELLO </p>
    <p> HELLO </p>
    <p> HELLO </p>
    <p> HELLO </p>
    <p> HELLO </p>
    <p> HELLO </p>
    <p> HELLO </p>
    <p> HELLO </p>
    <p> HELLO </p>
    <p> HELLO </p>
    <p> HELLO </p>
    <p> HELLO </p>
</div>
```

Then to make sure that the header doesn't overlap the body text, you need to give the body some padding at the top:

```
body{
    padding-top:60px;
}
```